# Parton distribution function - dependence on $Q$?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, partons

In one of my previous [questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/332919/do-electrons-interact-with-gluons) I define the parton distribution function, following that of [D.Stump](http://www.hep.wisc.edu/cteq11/lectures/DanStump.Lecture1.pdf) as follows:

> $f_i(x,Q^2)dx$ is the mean number of the $i$th type of patron with longitudinal momentum fraction from $x$ to $x+dx$ appropriate to a scattering experiment with momentum transfer $Q$.

I am slightly confused by the last term 'appropriate to a scattering experiment with momentum transfer $Q$'. How can the 'mean number of the $i$th type of patron with longitudinal momentum fraction from $x$ to $x+dx$'  (which seems to be an property of the proton) change depending on how we probe it? And why can we take:
$$\sum_i\int f_i(x,Q^2)dx=1~\forall~Q$$

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on why you think the mean number shouldn't change depending on the probe?

Comment: @DavidZ because if a patron is carrying $1/2$ of the proton momentum (say) this is a property of the patron and proton not of how it is been probed. If I measure it with a probe of any momentum transfer $Q$ I should get $1/2$ if I don't my measurement is surely wrong.

Comment: How can momentum be a property ? A ball is a ball whether it is moving or not. have a look at this http://moller.physics.berkeley.edu/~yury/Phys226/hadronStructure.pdf . It has been known forever that the structure functions of the proton are Q^2 dependent, i. e. the "size" depends on the transfer of momentum of the probe.  That is how we found the quarks, by increasing the momentum transfer and showing a rutherford type deep inelastic scattering.

Comment: please remember we are in special relativity doing particle physics, and the protons structure is not  fixed  on a number of particles.   see https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/

Comment: @annav You say 'It has been known forever that the structure of the proton are $Q^2$ dependent' - in the case when the structure of the proton contains 3 valance quarks (without gluons) then I believe the structure functions are independent of $Q^2$ (this is Bjorken scaling). I can't see how introducing gluon and sea quarks suddenly means our distribution functions depend on the prove. I guess the crux of my problem is that I can't see how changing $Q^2$ changes the distribution of momentum between the different types of parton.

Comment: Structure functions  are measured.. The parton model and then the QCD model just explain the data, which are q^2 dependent.  see http://pdg.lbl.gov/2011/reviews/rpp2011-rev-structure-functions.pdf fig 16.2 . Data trumps beliefs

Answer (score 3):

Consider the diagram below:

[image]

With a small momentum transfer $Q$ the resolution is low and you in essence interpret everything in $A$ as a single entity (a valance quark say) and as such associate with it a high Bjorken parameter $x$. As $Q$ increases your resolution increases and you see the quarks, antiquarks and gluons that once you thought made up this single entity. Naturally with each of these you associate a smaller value of $x$ and thus in this high $Q$ case you see lots of particles at low $x$ values and fewer at high $x$ values compared with the low $Q$ case. This should explain why you still require the total momentum fraction of all the partons to equal 1 (as explained by @Lê Dũng).

Answer (score 1):

The PDF $f_i(x,Q^2)$ is defined as the probability density (number densities as they are normalised to the number of partons - this can be the meaning of "mean number" in the definition of D.Stump) to find a parton of type i carrying a momentum fraction x at a the energy scale $Q^2$ (momentum transfer).

In QCD, there is a phenomenon called "asymptotic freedom", namely the interaction between partons inside a nucleon changes according to the distance (higher distance, stronger interaction and vice versa), or, equivalently, according to the energy scale. That is to say, the PDF should depend on the energy scale (as confirmed by DIS experiments, which you can search easilly).

And, I think the sum rule is not as you presented, but as follows:
$$\sum_i\int xf_i(x,Q^2)dx=1$$
This rule is from the fact that, the total momentum of all partons should be equal to the momentum of the nucleon.